# FreeBSD 8.2: Keystrokes in Bash do not show up

Tags: bash, shell, freebsd, prompt, input

I just installed the latest FreeBSD 8.2 distro using Parallels Desktop. Problem: Whatever I type in the Bash/Shell it is not echoed on the screen. It's behaving like a password prompt. As soon I hit return it's displayed though. This is really annoying and I've no idea what to do.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like it may be an issue with Parallels not capturing the keyboard input correctly. Try clicking on the VM to force capturing the mouse/keyboard, and see if that makes a difference. If that doesn't fix it, you can try using VirtualBox to see if it shows the same problem.

Just to let you know, FreeBSD uses csh as the default shell, not bash. You should be aware of this since some things are done differently, such as setting environment variables.

Comment: No it's not an issue with the keyboard input as it's captured by FreeBSD correctly. Mouse/Keyboard are assigned to the VM (clicked on it, otherwise I wouldn'd get any response). Keystrokes are just not seen while typing. As soon I hit return it's also seen on the screen. According to your tip I've also tried VirtualBox but there I had other problems with installation and stuff. Not sure what else to do. Thanks anyway.

Comment: Ok... I've never run into this problem running FreeBSD in in a VM or directly, but I've never run it on Apple hw. If you have a FreeBSD dvd, you can use it in live mode by selectinf `Fixit` form the main installer menu, then choosing live filesystem from CDROM/DVD. This will at least allow you to bypass OS-X & Parallels to test your hw directly with FreeBSD.